# Permanent Redirect of a variable URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having troubles with my .htaccess permanent redirection code which is not working:

```
RedirectPermanent ^shop/?attro-attributes=([0-9]*) http://www.second-website.example
```

I would like to redirect URLs from first-website:

- `first-website.example/shop/?attro-attributes=01`
- `first-website.example/shop/?attro-attributes=02`
- `first-website.example/shop/?attro-attributes=...`
- `first-website.example/shop/?attro-attributes=9999`

to second-website URL: `http://www.second-website.example/`

Comment: Check out this stack exchange answer, it looks like they were having a similar issue they were able to fix it by using ```RedirectMatch``` - https://serverfault.com/questions/825236/using-apache-redirectpermanent-to-send-all-requests-to-a-specific-subfolder

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or are you able to view the apache error logs to isolate where the issue might be and what error is happening?

Comment: @ColinMcCormack unfornately it's not :/

I don't know, what I'm sure of is that my code is not working properly

Comment: @Noware, this is not clear, you are showing 2 different urls to be redirected to single one, it could create problems in backend rewrite, so please do mention it more clearly in your question, thank you.

Comment: Here is the documentation for the directive you are using - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html I'm not quite sure what exactly the issue might be without an error message, but my suggestion would be to first try to redirect a single URL like this example and then build from there - https://serverfault.com/questions/344614/simple-apache2-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear, it's hard for me to explain what I'm looking for 

I've got my main URL that contain different values :
url/?attro-attributes=**XX**

and I want that when someone go into url/?attro-attributes=**XX**, it's redirecting to Second-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectPermanent` and other redirect directives from `mod_alias` have no access to the query string. Your match pattern can't contain the `?` from the URL or match on anything after it.

You'll instead have to use `mod_rewrite` which can access the query string via `RewriteCond`.

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attro-attributes=[0-9]*
RewriteRule ^/?shop/$ https://www.second-website.example/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you tell me if this going to rewrite only "?attro-attributes=XX" url or will rewrite any url after /shop/ (like /shop/product1 )?

Comment: The rewrite condition makes the following rewrite rule only apply when the condition matches.  So if the URL doesn't have the attributes in the query string, it won't redirect.  Furthermore, the rewrite rule itself ends in a `$` after `/shop/` so it won't redirect `/shop/product1` because the URL path has extra on it, even if it does have the proper query string.